# Using Spark to process multiple files in parallel without combining them at the end

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I currently have a list of `.txt.gz` files that are `.tsv` in nature (I cannot control the source file format, and they're all >10GB) that I essentially need to read in, unzip, and write out to a destination file path in parquet format for later processing.

**Each file is different in nature and shouldn't be combined - so I can't pass the full path.**

Right now I have a simple UDF that does some preprocessing on any filename, reads it in, and then attempts to write it back out to the directory - I pass this UDF and a list of filenames to a `.map` function hoping that it gets spread out across executors...a simple example would be if I had 4 files and 4 executors each with 3 cores then each executor would get it's own file, and it would unzip/read in that file (ideally onto 3 partitions for one of each of the 3 cores), and then write it back out into parquet format

```
// Find a file, unzip it, partition and write to parquet with no filename extension
def unzip_and_write_delta(fileName:String, outFileDir:String) : Int = {
  val inFileDir:String = if (domino_source.contains(fileName)) mounted_source_filepath1 else mounted_source_filepath2
  val inFullPath:String = inFileDir.concat(fileName)
  
  val fileOutputName = fileName.replace(".txt.gz", "") //.replace(".rar", "")
  val outFullPath:String = outFileDir.concat(fileOutputName)

  val returned = spark.read.option("sep", "\t").option("header", "true").option("numPartitions", 3).csv(inFullPath).write.parquet(outFullPath)
  // val returned = sc.textFile(inFullPath).map(_.split("\t")).write.parquet(outFullPath)
  return 0
}
```

This function is then fed to a map function:

```
val out_val = full_filelist.map(
  f => unzip_and_write_delta(fileName=f, outFileDir=mounted_target_filepath)
)
```

The sc.textFile command seemed to work yesterday, but the results were filled with bad encodings, and so I switched it to the `spark.read.option` today and now neither of them seem to be doing anything in parallel...each file is loaded sequentially onto a single partition on a single executor and the entire thing is read and then written out ultimately bypassing any efficiency gains.

[Executor Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5KGZ.png)

I've tried multiple combinations of the spark.read and sc.textFile commands, both with and without the `repartition` command, both setting an option of `numPartitions`, and with and without the `list.map()` function and nothing seems to be working in parallel

At a minimum I'm hoping to at least have each executor process it's own file, and as a bonus being able to read and process across cores (can't find much for csv, but seems to be options for textFile...although the encodings don't work well)

Comment: There is another thread on this that I admit I missed: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912858/processing-multiple-files-as-independent-rdds-in-parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting at least things ran in parallel was solved by adding `.par` to the map function

```
val out_val = full_filelist.par.map(
  f => unzip_and_write_delta(fileName=f, outFileDir=mounted_target_filepath)
)
```

which resulted in this executor panel:
[Executor Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfPgx.png)